# Is it a good idea to have classes of relationship types for questions to create context?

Tags: discussion, scope, tags, asking-questions

Is it a good idea to have classes of relationship types for questions? By this I mean, [family](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/family), [close-friends](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/close-friends), etc

A question like this [Asking someone to check out something I created](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/41/asking-someone-to-check-out-something-i-created) could be construed as a little broad, as it would vary greatly depending upon whom the pitch was aimed at. An [acquaintances](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acquaintances) would be very different from a [romance](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romance).

A relationship type creates [context](http://engagedhr.com/the-importance-of-context/):

> The hardest thing about communicating effectively is knowing how to “set the context”.

There are many other ways to assist with providing context, but the relationship type is an opening generic category that helps to define the scernario.

Given this is a site for interpersonal skills, it would be good to have a clear definition of what is on-topic and how it should be asked. So this is one attempt to help clarify this; as a demonstration of our interpersonal skills...? :)

There would be some cases where the tag was not needed for clarification, but my thoughts are that it is usually helpful. What do you all think?

Comment: I think you are absolutely right. But I am having difficulty honing in on where exactly to draw those lines.

Comment: @John of course, we won't really be able to draw lines in concrete - it will be a developing thing. I just thought while it's teeny tiny and easier to implement, it might not be a bad idea to organise- basically every question has to involve a third party - so why not place that person into a group. Good for SEO. Assists with context.

Comment: I totally agree. I think your examples are spot on, and should be the basis on which we build a more complete list. I just wanted to say as much, while being unable to further the concept along.

Answer (score 5):

### Definately, without a doubt.

As I've been told in both my questions now (and what no doubt I'll be reminded in questions to come) is that the devil.is indeed in the detail. We could have tags for all sorts of relationships, and I think we should encourage more tags in this private beta. However once public beta comes out, or further down the line of private beta, we should try and trip this number down by removing similar tags or see what tags can be merged into one. We want to make sure we have tags for everything, but without missing any out. This private beta is the perfect opportunity to find all those tags.